# Highcharts / Highstock horizontal plotLine label's vertical alignment?

Tags: highcharts

How can I align the labels text vertically when using horizontal plotlines? I would like the plotline to be in the vertical middle of the text labels!

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [y parameter](http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#yAxis.labels.y) for labels

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: Why this not answer for this question? you can move labels up to, and achieve his goal.